# How to estimate the minimum number in a implicit function?

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

Suppose positive number $t$ and $\alpha$ satisfying
$$\alpha>t+\sqrt 2
$$
and $$t \alpha^2-2(t^2+1)\alpha+t^3\geq0$$

What I want to do is to find the minimum number $\alpha$ such that both equations above hold simultaneously.

Maybe it's hard to find exact solution, so it would be better if there is any numerical method to find approximate solution.

Comment: Set $\alpha = t+\sqrt 2 +s$ and substitute into second inequality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: the second inequality can be written as $(\alpha-(t+\frac  1t))^{2} \geq \frac 1  {t^{2}}+2$ or $|\alpha -(t+\frac  1t)| \geq \frac {\sqrt {t^{2}+2}} 2$. Consider the cases $\alpha \geq t+\frac  1t$ and $\alpha < t+\frac  1t$  separately.